# Render TIFF image in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, rendering, tiff

I have TIFF images in the database, and I need to render them in Flex.

Please consider server-side conversion options as falling outside the scope of this question.  Client-side conversion options interest me, if anyone has anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/windowsbitmapdencoder) which seems to have some AS3 / Flex client-side Tiff support.  Check out the [code in SVN](http://code.google.com/p/windowsbitmapdencoder/source/browse/#svn/trunk/ImageDencoder/src/com/ctyeung/TIFFbaseline).