# Display Tiff file in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, tiff

I am trying to display a tiff in a Flex Desktop Applications.

i tried displaying it with image tag but i does not works.
It says that it is not a recognized format. 
I need to find a way to display it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render TIFF image in Flex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428740/render-tiff-image-in-flex)

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428740/render-tiff-image-in-flex ; specifically look at this project: http://code.google.com/p/windowsbitmapdencoder/

Comment: I tried that before with the tif images from [this sample images](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/index.htm) <CCITT_1.TIF>  but it does not seems to work. It says that it failed TIFF decoding and compression failed. Just to ensure that i am correct, i downloaded the imageDEncoder(http://code.google.com/p/windowsbitmapdencoder/downloads/list) from the source given

Comment: Hey , just a question, is there different version of TIF, that's why it cant be read?